# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException and org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have developed server program using spring mvc and hibernate but I'm getting an error at runtime

This is servlet-context.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jinggumdari" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="mysql1234" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Member</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="memberDAO" class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.MemberDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="memberService"
        class="kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation.MemberManageServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="memberDAO" ref="memberDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>



    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

and It is error message

```html
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jinggumdariController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.service.MemberManageService kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.controller.JinggumdariController.MemberManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.service.MemberManageService] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: memberManageServiceImpl,memberService
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5550)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

and my code:

```java
package kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.controller;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Member;
import kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.service.MemberManageService;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

/**
 * Handles requests for the application home page.
 */
@Controller
public class JinggumdariController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JinggumdariController.class);

    @Autowired
    private MemberManageService MemberManager;

    private boolean isSuccess;
    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/member/signIn", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody boolean signIn(@RequestParam("email") String email,
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        isSuccess = false;
        Member member = new Member(email, password);

        isSuccess = MemberManager.addMember(member); 
        return isSuccess;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/member/getInfo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody Member getMember(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
        Member member = MemberManager.getMember(email);
        return member;
    }

    //출력 예시 코드
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String test2() {
        return "이젠 이걸 쓸거임";
    }
}
```

```java
package kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.service;

import kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Member;

public interface MemberManageService {
    public boolean addMember(Member member);
    public boolean modifyMember(Member member);
    public boolean removeMember(String email);
    public Member getMember(String email);
}
```

```java
 package kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.serviceImplementation;

    import kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.DAO.MemberDAO;
    import kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.model.Member;
    import kr.ac.jbnu.jinggumdari.service.MemberManageService;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
    import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

    @Service
    public class MemberManageServiceImpl implements MemberManageService{
        private MemberDAO memberDAO;

        public void setMemberDAO(MemberDAO memberDAO) {
            this.memberDAO = memberDAO;
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public boolean addMember(Member member) {
            return memberDAO.addMember(member);
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public boolean modifyMember(Member member) {
            return memberDAO.modifyMember(member);
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public boolean removeMember(String email) {
            return removeMember(email);
        }

        @Override
        @Transactional
        public Member getMember(String email) {
            return memberDAO.getMember(email);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is pretty clear, `expected single matching bean but found 2: memberManageServiceImpl,memberService`

You are creating bean in your `xml` (having id: `memberService`) and also using annotation `@Service` (having id: `memberManageServiceImpl`). You need to decide which one you want and remove other.

Comment: thank you very much!!
I can have solved this problem according to your answer.

Comment: @Rect, if it solved your problem, then you can [accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) it.